# search in saved eventlog-file with powershell

Tags: powershell, filter, event-log

I have got some saved eventlogfiles (*.evtx).
I want to search the ml-data for a specific textstring.

I found this solution for the current system eventlog:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName APPLICATION -After 04/01/2018 | Where-Object { $_.Message -like '*AVAST*' }
```

Is it possible to search a saved eventlog file with this string?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Get-WinEvent** cmdlet,

```
Get-WinEvent -Path C:\file.evtx | Where-Object { $_.Message -like '*AVAST*' }
```